# How to position JOptionPane.showMessageDialog at the center of screen?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Currently,the dialog box pops up just below the clicked Jbutton component.

Comment: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello world");`

Comment: *"the dialog box pops up just below the clicked Jbutton component."*  I tend to provide the top level container as the argument and it will be centered over that window.  That is logical for the user.

Comment: @user3218114 Are you the same user? :D

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: try `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Hello world");` to to show it in the center of the frame/window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To center an option pane on-screen, provide a `null` parent, but note then that parent component GUI won't be blocked to the user.

E.G.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.*;

class CenterTheDialog {

    CenterTheDialog() {
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Show over parent?");
        for (int ii=1; ii<4; ii++) {
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame " + ii);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            Component parent = (JOptionPane.OK_OPTION==result ? f : null);

            f.setSize(400,300);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            f.setVisible(true);

            JDialog d = new JDialog(f);
            d.setTitle("Dialog " + ii);
            d.setSize(300,200);
            d.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
            d.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CenterTheDialog();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: the popu-up will be shown behind the frame.

Comment: @user3218114 No, it won't.  I just checked it.

Answer (score 10):

You may try this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Hello");
```

or

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Hello");
```

From the Java Docs:

> parentComponent : Defines the Component that is to be the parent of
>   this dialog box. It is used in two ways: the Frame that contains it is
>   used as the Frame parent for the dialog box, and its screen
>   coordinates are used in the placement of the dialog box. In general,
>   the dialog box is placed just below the component. This parameter may
>   be null, in which case a default Frame is used as the parent, and the
>   dialog will be centered on the screen (depending on the L&F).